# Accessing property is not possible

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I want to display a separate `SubjectView` in the `MainView`.

The property `topics` on `subject` in `SubjectView` is not accessible.

What should I do about it? Thanks.

---

**Update**:

```
ForEach(subject.topics, id: \.self) { topic in
    Text(topic.title)
}
```

... could be the problematic part.

---

File: `SubjectView`

```
import SwiftUI

struct SubjectView: View {
    @State var subject: Subject
    
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(subject.topics, id: \.self) { topic in
                Text(topic.title)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

File `MainView`

```
import SwiftUI

struct MainView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    
    @FetchRequest(entity: Subject.entity(), sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Subject.name, ascending: true)]) var subjects: FetchedResults<Subject>
    
    @State var subjectName: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                List {
                    ForEach(subjects, id: \.self) { subject in
                        NavigationLink(
                            destination: SubjectView(subject: subject),
                            label: {
                                Text(subject.name ?? "-")
                            })
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Schulfächer")
        }
    }
}
```

[Screenshot of the Subject entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvWaM.jpg)

The error at `SubjectView`: `var body: some View` reads:

```
Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please submit a bug report (https://swift.org/contributing/#reporting-bugs) and include the project
```

Comment: You should probably show `Subject`.

Comment: Subject is created by XCode

Comment: Unrelated but `@State` in `SubjectView ` makes no sense. `@State` is for value types, for reference types there is `@StateObject`. But as this object is actually not *the source of truth* and is reference type anyway just declare  `let subject: Subject`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@State var subject: Subject
```

in `SubjectView` should be

```
@ObservedObject var subject: Subject
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app

`@StateObject` is for initializing `ObservableObject`s

As for your topics

```
ForEach((subject.topics.allObjects as? [Topic]) ?? [], id: \.self) { topic in
```

Should work

Comment: The view doesn't seem to modify the Core Data record. So `@ObservedObject` is overkill.

Comment: Maybe I’m assuming there will be more since the user has a loop. It also updates the view when the changes are made elsewhere

Comment: another question: my data is not persisted. Do you know why? Thanks!

Comment: Persisted? Nothing in your code shows persistence. Are you saving?

Comment: managedObjectContext.save() ? some Button causes that.

Comment: Yup that should work put that code in a `Button` make sure you are using `do try catch`. Also, make sure you are using `@ObservedObject` to see the changes in the CoreData objects. Each `subject` and `topic` would need one.

Comment: what do you mean with @ObservedObject?

Comment: where should I use it?

Comment: Look at the first few lines of the answer

Answer (score 1):

The collection type of `ForEach` must conform to `RandomAccessCollection`. `topics` does not because it's an `(NS)Set`.

A simple solution is to `sort` the `Set` which becomes an `Array`. Or create an array explicitly, the line assumes that `topics` is a native Swift `Set<Topic>`

```
Array(subject.topics)
```

Note: Do not use `\.self` carelessly. Determine one attribute which is unique and/or adopt `Identifiable`. For example you could use the `NSManagedObjectID` of the `NSManagedObject` instance which is unique.